# How to select the entry with the lowest mean per group

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (2, 2, 'A', .5),
    (2, 2, 'A', .6),
    (2, 2, 'B', .75),
    (2, 2, 'B', .7),
    (2, 2, 'C', .6),

    (2, 3, 'A', .65),
    (2, 3, 'A', .6),
    (2, 3, 'B', .75),
    (2, 3, 'B', .7),
    (2, 3, 'C', .6)
], columns=['out_size', 'problem_size', 'algo', 'time'])
```

I want to

- group by `[out_size', 'problem_size', 'algo'], and for each group
- <s>count the number of occurrences for each `algo`, then</s>
- select/keep the `algo` that has the lowest average time in that group,

result

```
pd.DataFrame(
      [[2, 2, 'A', 0.55],
       [2, 3, 'C', 0.6]], columns=['out_size', 'problem_size', 'algo', 'time'])
```

Comment: PS: (Sorry) I just missed a detail that might be important. There are actually more columns to be average than `time`. Though all columns can be average as well, the decision on which entry (including `time` and all other columns) to keep per group is based upon `time` only.

Comment: If I reformulate, do you want to find the algo with lowest mean of time per group of out_size+problem_size?

Comment: Pretty much, but there are more information for each entry than just time, such as memory, etc. I didn't include here for simplicity.

Comment: I assume that the groupby would need to include 'algo' as well.

Comment: Can you try if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72777827/16343464) is doing what you want? If not, can you provide a counter-example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double `groupby`:

```
cols = ['out_size', 'problem_size', 'algo']

out = (df
 .groupby(cols, as_index=False)['time'].mean()
 .sort_values(by='time')
 .groupby(cols[:-1], as_index=False).first()
)
```

Slightly more efficient alternative that doesn't require to sort the values (but requires to store an intermediate):

```
cols = ['out_size', 'problem_size', 'algo']

out = df.groupby(cols)['time'].mean()
out = out.loc[out.groupby(cols[:-1]).idxmin()].reset_index()
```

output:

```
   out_size  problem_size algo  time
0         2             2    A  0.55
1         2             3    C  0.60
```

Comment: @rafaelc can you elaborate? This selects the algo with the lowest mean, per group of out_size+problem_size, which I believe is what is wanted

Comment: @rafaelc that's not how I understand it, I assume the count was to calculate the mean, but not involved in the decision

Comment: I made your second method into a 1-liner~

Comment: @BeRT2me but that makes it computationally less efficient (need to compute twice the min and agg on axis=1 is quite slow) ;)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. `idxmin` and `min` are going to be calculated separately, rather than looking up the `min` with the `idxmin` in two steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in one line by - grouping values, sorting & grouping again:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['out_size', 'problem_size', 'algo'])['time'].mean().reset_index()
df1 = df1.sort_values(['out_size', 'problem_size', 'time'])
df1 = df1.groupby(['out_size', 'problem_size']).head(1)
df1
```

Output:

```
   out_size  problem_size algo  time
      2             2      A     0.55
      2             3      C     0.60
```

Comment: this doesn't give the correct answer ;)

Comment: Modified, it should produce the correct output now.

Comment: Yes, but now it's the same as the 3 other answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two `groupby`s:

```
group_cols = ["out_size", "problem_size", "algo"]
result = df.groupby(group_cols)["time"].mean().reset_index(drop=False)
```

computes the mean time for each group. Then you can sort the time in ascending order:

```
result = result.sort_values("time", ascending=True)
```

and then group again (without column `algo`) and take the first element of each group:

```
result = result.groupby(["out_size", "problem_size"])[["algo","time"]].first().reset_index(drop=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do - first groupby the three columns and then agg by mean and then sort ascending and then you want to take only the first in the groups, so drop duplicates based on out_size and problem_size and keeping only the first which will guarantee you get the lowest average algo because it was already sorted.

```
df.groupby(['out_size', 'problem_size', 'algo'],as_index=False).agg(
    {'time':'mean'}).sort_values(
    by='time',ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(
    subset=['out_size', 'problem_size'], keep='first', ignore_index=True)
```

Or if you have more columns that all need average agg, then

```
agg_cols = ['time', #someother columns]
groupby_cols = df.columns.drop(agg_cols).tolist()
g = df.groupby(groupby_cols,as_index=False).agg('mean')
g.sort_values(by='time',ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(
               subset=['out_size','problem_size'],ignore_index=True, keep='first')
```

output:

```
   out_size  problem_size algo  time
0         2             2    A  0.55
1         2             3    C  0.60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cols = ['out_size', 'problem_size', 'algo']
out = df.groupby(cols)['time'].mean().unstack('algo').agg(['idxmin', 'min'], axis=1).reset_index()
out.rename(columns={'idxmin':'algo', 'min':'time'}, inplace=True)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   out_size  problem_size algo  time
0         2             2    A  0.55
1         2             3    C   0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['out_size', 'problem_size']).apply(lambda dd:dd.groupby('algo')['time'].mean().nsmallest(1)).reset_index()
```

output:

```
   out_size  problem_size algo  time
0         2             2    A  0.55
1         2             3    C  0.60
```